# How to fill down in Numbers without dragging?

Tags: numbers

I have a 20,000 line spreadsheet in Apple Numbers, and I need to fill a column with data. I don't want to sit there dragging down the fill handle for thousands of rows.

How can I fill the whole column with a value?

Comment: Fill it with data meaning: a) Copy the data from the top cell to all cells b) Fill and increment the value?

Comment: Either. If the column should be 'True' copy that down into all 20,000 cells. If it should be 1,2,3 incrementing copy those 3 numbers and fill down incrementing.

Answer (score 28):

Found a way.

1. Select the column
2. Deselect the header row (Cmd click on the header
   row cell)
3. Table Menu > Autofill Cells > Autofill Down

This will ​not​ infer a pattern. (ex 1,2,3 it will just copy down 1,1,1)

If you’re expect it to interpolate, you have to click-drag.

It will fill down formulas and they will be correct.

Answer (score 10):

It is late for response here.

I have a file with 65500 rows which I need to add sequence of numbers (1,2,3,etc) to it. This is how you do it.

Row 1, column 1 type 1
In Row 2, column 2 type use formula to add the value of number 1 ( check the attachment)

Now do this as @Joshua Dance suggested.

1. Select the column
2. Deselect the header row and the row 1 (Cmd click on the header
   row cell)
3. Table Menu > Autofill Cells > Autofill Down

Cheers

[image]

Comment: If you actually want the values (eg: if you need to change the order of the rows and added the new column to keep track of original order), you can copy the whole column then "paste formula values".

Comment: This is a great answer! i wish i'd thought of it years ago.. Simple, easy, works.. 
Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon the above answers, if you would like to do this using only the keyboard, you can simulate the Ctrl-D and Ctrl-R shortcuts from Excel by adding a keyboard shortcut to that menu item in System Preferences.

This is how:

1. Open System Preferences > Keyboard
2. Under the Shortcuts tab, click the + button.

   In the resulting sheet, select Numbers.app for the Application.

   For Menu Title, enter Autofill Down, exactly as it is in the menu item.

   For Keyboard Shortcut, press the key combination you want to assign, e.g. Ctrl-D or Ctrl-R.

Answer (score 0):

Filling a column can use the shortcut combination "option + command + \".

Steps:

1. Select the column you want to fill in.
2. Unselect the first cell.
3. Press "option + command + \" at the same time.